# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 6

Tags: apex

```
list<integer> mynums = new list<integer>();
mynums.add(10);
mynums.add(20);
mynums.add(30);
mynums.add(20);
mynums.add(10);
mynums.add(5,60);
system.debug('list values'+mynums);
```

This is my code,when i want to insert an other number with index 5 it is throwing an error as shown above.
Help me out.............

Answer (score 1):

First make `List<Integer>` instead of `list` it is error.

second since index 5 value is not initiated yet you cannot push value directly at 5 index try to push it at 4 and it will work.

hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect Answer :) It works.

Comment: Yea,i Know that works,but why can't i do in this way?